# Error with install a package by using "devtools"

Tags: r, installation, devtools

```
Package (under development): ACRER 
computer: iMAC (OS X 10.15.7) 
RStudio version: 1.4.1717 
R version: 4.1.0
```

The package "ACRER" has a main script "Wageningen_SQLite_2020.R" and 4 functions (Run_Queries.R,Wcombinations.R,Wexpected_visit_duration.R and Wcrosstab.R with 4 sub functions:NGroup0.R, NGroup1.R,NGroup2.R, NGroup3.R and NGroup4.R).

I get this error:

```r
devtools::install(pkg = "/Volumes/Aias/ACRER", reload = TRUE, 
    build = TRUE, quiet = FALSE, build_vignettes = FALSE, force = TRUE)
```

> Error in grepRaw("00new", r, fixed = TRUE, all = FALSE, value = FALSE) :
> long vectors not supported yet: /Volumes/Builds/R4/R-4.1.0/src/main/grep.c:1450

(see reprex code bellow)
I would appreciate if somebody can give me some suggestions about this problem

```r
devtools::install(pkg = "/Volumes/Aias/ACRER", reload = TRUE, 
    build = TRUE, quiet = FALSE, build_vignettes = FALSE, force = TRUE)
#> Skipping 1 packages not available: intpoint
#> Skipping 1 packages ahead of CRAN: data.table
#>      checking for file ‘/Volumes/Aias/ACRER/DESCRIPTION’ ...  ✓  checking for file ‘/Volumes/Aias/ACRER/DESCRIPTION’
#>   ─  preparing ‘ACRER’: (40.4s)
#>   ✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
#>   ─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
#>   ─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
#>      Removed empty directory ‘ACRER/tests/testthat’
#> ─  building ‘ACRER_0.9.1.tar.gz’
#>      
#> Running /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD INSTALL \
#>   /var/folders/6h/lzdkxf9j07bd1q5t82lphhjc0000gn/T//RtmpkmZA7M/ACRER_0.9.1.tar.gz \
#>   --install-tests 
#> * installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library’
#> * installing *source* package ‘ACRER’ ...
#> ** using staged installation
#> ** R
#> ** data
#> *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
#> ** tests
#> ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
#> Wcrosstab(Rmatrix = RmatrixA, Cmatrix = CmatrixA, C1 = C1A)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'activity_pattern'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> Wcrosstab(Rmatrix = RmatrixB, Cmatrix = CmatrixB, C1 = C1B)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'groupsRecr_act_ts'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> Warning in xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
#> Wcrosstab(Rmatrix = RmatrixC, Cmatrix = CmatrixC, C1 = C1C)
#> Warning in rm(list = c("Run_Queries", "Wcombinations", "Wcrosstab", "Wexpected_visit_duration",  :
#>   object 'Wcombinations' not found
#> Warning in rm(list = c("Run_Queries", "Wcombinations", "Wcrosstab", "Wexpected_visit_duration",  :
#>   object 'Wcrosstab' not found
#> Warning in rm(list = c("Run_Queries", "Wcombinations", "Wcrosstab", "Wexpected_visit_duration",  :
#>   object 'Wexpected_visit_duration' not found
#>      choicenr choicetxt                                        
#> [1,] "1"      "Pivot table for the number of persons"          
#> [2,] "2"      "Pivot tables for the expected visiting duration"
#> [3,] "3"      "Save tables in csv format files"                
#> [4,] "4"      "Exit"                                           
#>    RecrID                   recreation_areas
#> 1       1           Beeldengalerij Het Depot
#> 2       2                 Arboretum Belmonte
#> 3       3         Wageningen Berg en Bergpad
#> 4       4               Arboretum de Dreijen
#> 5       5              Uitwaarden Wageningen
#> 6       6                    Renkums Beekdal
#> 7       7     Utrechtse Heuvelrug_Grebbeberg
#> 8       8                    De Blauwe Kamer
#> 9       9        Ouwehands Dierenpark Rhenen
#> 10     10                  Kasteel Doorwerth
#> 11     11                          Edese bos
#> 12     12        AIRBORNE MUSEUM HARTENSTEIN
#> 13     13            Peppelenburg Westerrode
#> 14     14                   Landgoed Kernhem
#> 15     15                     Wekeromse Zand
#> 16     16                          De Betuwe
#> 17     17                             Roekel
#> 18     18         Hoog en Laag Amerongse Bos
#> 19     19                       Noord Ginkel
#> 20     20              Amerongse Bovenpolder
#> 21     21                 Lunters Buurtbosch
#> 22     22                          WARNSBORN
#> 23     23                     PARK ZYPENDAAL
#> 24     24                        Zuid Ginkel
#> 25     25  HET NATIONALE PARK DE HOGE VELUWE
#> 26     26                        BURGERS ZOO
#> 27     27                      PARK SONSBEEK
#> 28     28     HET NEDERLANDS OPENLUCHTMUSEUM
#> 29     29                  PARK ANGERENSTEIN
#> 30     30          PARK EN KASTEEL ROSENDAEL
#> 31     31 Nationaal Park_Utrechtse Heuvelrug
#> 32     32                    GROESBEEKSE BOS
#> 33     33          VELUWETRANSFERIUM POSBANK
#>   transport_type_ID transport_type_definition maximum_of_total_time
#> 1                 1                   on foot                    60
#> 2                 2                   bicycle                    50
#> 3                 3                       car                    40
#>   wait_time_per_full_travel minimum_distance_used maximum_distance_used
#> 1                         0                     0                     0
#> 2                         0                     0                    25
#> 3                         0                     0                   100
#>   speed_of_transport_type fixed_costs_per_transport_type
#> 1                       0                              0
#> 2                      20                              0
#> 3                      60                              0
#>   per_km_costs_per_transport_type per_person_costs_per_transport_type
#> 1                            0.00                                   0
#> 2                            0.00                                   0
#> 3                            0.65                                   0
#>   per_km_en_per_person_costs_per_transport_type
#> 1                                             0
#> 2                                             0
#> 3                                             0
#> ** help
#> *** installing help indices
#> ** building package indices
#> ** installing vignettes
#> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
#> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
#> ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
#> Error in grepRaw("00new", r, fixed = TRUE, all = FALSE, value = FALSE) : 
#>   long vectors not supported yet: /Volumes/Builds/R4/R-4.1.0/src/main/grep.c:1450
#> * removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/ACRER’
#> Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, : System command 'R' failed, exit status: 1, stdout & stderr were printed
```

Comment: I'm assuming [this](https://github.com/martakis/ACRER) is the package in mind?

Comment: Try to install from R directly?  I wonder if you've got the same problem as this asker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674526/package-installation-exiting-with-status-1