# Package installation exiting with status 1

Tags: r

I have a small package with a handful of functions that I have previously installed successfully on my local machine (i.e. not a CRAN package). I made some updates to these functions and their supporting data, and am trying to use the RStudio "clean and rebuild" pipeline to reinstall the updated package. I've gotten an error I don't understand and have not had success in tracing. It appears to result from a call to grep.c that happens as or after it is trying to identify the temporary directory in which it had been installed first, but I don't know how to inspect the source code behind this to identify what is being grepped, why, or why it is failing.

I have tried this from a clean run of RStudio (i.e. no other projects open, nothing else running, no optional packages loaded). I have not tried it from the console within RStudio (I'm not actually sure how to do so, or if it's possible), so if there's a way to do something akin to traceback(), I'm not aware of it.

This is the full output I get from the failed installation.

```
>==> Rcmd.exe INSTALL --no-multiarch --with-keep.source WRAPNorms
>
>* installing to library 'C:/Users/jonaitis/Documents/R/win-library/4.0'
>* installing *source* package 'WRAPNorms' ...
>** using staged installation
>** R
>** inst
>** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
>** help
>*** installing help indices
>  converting help for package 'WRAPNorms'
>    finding HTML links ...    WRAP_est                                html  
>    WRAP_harm                               html   done
>
>    finding level-2 HTML links ...
>    convert_missing_wrap                    html   done
>
>    hello                                   html  
>    recode_values                           html  
>** building package indices
>** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
>** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
>** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
>Error in grepRaw("00new", r, fixed = TRUE, all = FALSE, value = FALSE) : 
>  long vectors not supported yet: grep.c:1449
>* removing 'C:/Users/jonaitis/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/WRAPNorms'
>* restoring previous 'C:/Users/jonaitis/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/WRAPNorms'
>
>Exited with status 1.
```

**Edit:** I have now tried installing using devtools procedures from the RStudio command line. It still fails, but now I have a little more information. Here's the end of the console output.

```
> ** building package indices
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
> *** arch - i386
> *** arch - x64
> ** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
> *** arch - i386
> *** arch - x64
> ** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
> Error in grepRaw("00new", r, fixed = TRUE, all = FALSE, value = FALSE) : 
  long vectors not supported yet: grep.c:1450
> * removing 'C:/Users/jonaitis/Documents/R/R-4.1.2/library/WRAPNorms'
> Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  : 
>  System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed, exit status: 1, stdout & stderr were printed
> Type .Last.error.trace to see where the error occurred
> > .Last.error.trace
>
>  Stack trace:
>
> 1. devtools:::install()
> 2. pkgbuild::with_build_tools(required = FALSE, callr::rcmd("INSTALL",  ...
> 3. withr::with_path(rtools_path(), code)
> 4. base:::force(code)
> 5. callr::rcmd("INSTALL", c(install_path, opts), echo = !quiet,  ...
> 6. callr:::run_r(options)
> 7. base:::with(options, with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run,  ...
> 8. base:::with.default(options, with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run,  ...
> 9. base:::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
> 10. base:::eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
> 11. callr:::with_envvar(env, do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, args = real_cmdargs,  ...
> 12. base:::force(code)
> 13. base:::do.call(processx::run, c(list(bin, args = real_cmdargs,  ...
> 14. (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  ...
> 15. throw(new_process_error(res, call = sys.call(), echo = echo,  ...
```

Comment: Same problem with 4.1 I assume?

Comment: Good question. Yes, I get the same error trying to install it on a different machine, version 4.1.2. Although the line number on which grep.c fails is 1450 rather than 1449. No idea whether that's a meaningful difference.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the whole package directory and installing this package first?  That would narrow the issue down to be just the install of this package and not some lingering state from the previous install.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand -- are you suggesting that I delete this single package directory, or the directory where all installed packages go? Assuming the former, I think it will not work, as one of the two machines I've tried on is new, and has not yet had this package installed (so in effect it's a fresh installation of this single package).